# Build libaacplus on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: build, ffmpeg

I try to compile `libaacplus` using this (coming from [FFMPEG](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide) website) :

```
wget http://217.20.164.161/~tipok/aacplus/libaacplus-2.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzf libaacplus-2.0.2.tar.gz
cd libaacplus-2.0.2
sed -i '.bck' -e 's/libtool/glibtool/' autogen.sh
./autogen.sh
make
make install
```

It fails at `make` step :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive 
Making all in src 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 
Making all in include make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 
Making all in patches make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 
Making all in frontend 
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o aacplusenc main.o ../src/libaacplus.la -lm  
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/aacplusenc main.o  ../src/.libs/libaacplus.dylib -lm     
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_AuChannelOpen", referenced from:
      _main in main.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
make[2]: *** [aacplusenc] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I succeed to build when I was using 10.8.x but totally unable to do it with 10.9.x... Any clue ?

Merry Christmas

Comment: I recommend compiling libfdk-aac instead. libaacplus is often more trouble to compile. libfdk-aac has the advantage of being able to encode both AAC-LC and AAC-HE. See [How to Compile FFmpeg on OS X](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide) for more info.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard so you recommend me not to do what I want to and link me to the website I already mention in the question...

Comment: Yes, and I missed your poorly named link. I see no reason to compile libaacplus when you can use libfdk-aac instead. Some users have reported conflicts between these encoders or some other issue that prevents both from being supported at the same time, but I have not investigated this.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ok, I followed your advice and compile FFMpeg with libaacplus but now it seems that some libs (all libav* libs) are corrupted... It throws a lot of messages like this one : `"_SSL_ctrl", referenced from:_tls_open in libavformat.a(tls.o)`

Comment: Are the messages showing up during `make`? What `./configure` options are you using for ffmpeg?

Comment: Nevermind, that's not linked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Actually the "AuChannelOpen" method was implement in frontend/au_channel.h file, but it was a "inline" method. I think that the Makefile disabled the "inline" feature, so simple solutions:

1. enable "inline".
2. delete all "inline" words in au_channel.h file.
3. and if you just need the static library without the program, you can commit the line where call this function in frontend/main.c.